# how to set language of fullCalendar dynamically

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, fullcalendar

I want to use a full calendar with different languages, I get the selected language from a dropdown and I keep the value in a factory, to update this value I'm using a watch.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
        return langFctr.selectedLang;
    },
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (oldValue != newValue) {
            $scope.selectedLang = newValue;
            if (newValue) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'lang', $scope.selectedLang);
            }
            console.log($('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'lang', $scope.selectedLang));
            console.log($scope.selectedLang);
        }
    }
);
```

In the watch (after the value of the selected language change) I try to change the language of the calendar but It doesn't work

Comment: Did you see this http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ ?

Comment: I'm not working directly with the directive I've the component in my template and there is my code http://pastebin.com/md8TiA4d for the function update it update the list of event and it's working well but when I try to change the config with the same logic it didn't work

Comment: Did you load the language file(s) for fullcalendar? Either from lang/ folder or lang-all.js? https://jsfiddle.net/011k8jf3/

Comment: @smcd I tried both of them I think the problem is with my component it don't detect the changed language and when I try with some language 'es' for example the translation is done